# About expressions such as on a walk, on a hike, on a ride

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about such idiomatic prepositional expressions where **on** is used as on a walk, on a hike, on a stroll, on a climb, on a ride, on vacation, on leave, on offer, on show, on display, on a mission, on an expedition, on stock, on reserve, on a picnic, on sale... etc.

As far as I research, I presume they tend to have something to do with a figurative situation.
I mean such expressions I wrote down seem to be deeply related with the state **which requires a subject to stand on a surface.**
I am not insisting all expressions with on can be explained by the reason, but at least those above.

To explain,

On as in on a walk is used for expressing the situation where a subject is walking **on** a street.

On as in on a hike is used for expressing the situation where a subject is hiking **on** a mountain path.

On as in on vacation is used for expressing the situation where a subject is doing activities standing **on** the state of vacation.

On as in on reserve is used for expressing the situation where a subject is reserved **on** a place.

On as in on sale is used for expressing the situation where a subject is put **on** a special place for selling the subject at a discount.

What do you think of my presuming? 
Is it plausible at all?

Comment: How about, `I'm on an ocean voyage,` `He's on leave from the Army,`, or `She's on sabbatical`? Your supposition makes some sense, but is not broad enough. Perhaps the intent is `taking part in a long term (well, at least a day) activity`?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik I think **on** as in on an ocean voyage is for expressing "I'm **on** the surface of the sea"(though precisely speaking, a ship or cruise I'm on is on the surface of the sea), **on** as in on leave is for expressing "I'm doing activities standing **on** the state of **leaving**, and **on** as in on sabbatical is for expressing "I'm doing activities standing **on** the state of **being sabbatical**

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, "***on***" is used to express *taking part in something which is progressing*

> **on** a walk
>   **on** a ride
>   **on** a trip

which really has nothing to do with the *physical location* of the participant.

Someone can also be

> **on** fire *(meaning successful)*
>   **on** a roll
>   **on** the top of the world

none of these references have a literal meaning of *location* or *state*.